# input type checkbox cannot check

Tags: php, wordpress, function, checkbox, input

I create a function to remove link in column table and change to input type checkbox but my checkbox it not working and cannot be checked

```
add_filter ('wpdatatables_filter_link_cell', 'wp_filter_link_cell', 2 );

function wp_filter_link_cell( $formattedValue ){

    $formattedValue = strip_tags($formttedValue);

    return '<input type="checkbox">' . $formattedValue . '</br>';
}
```

Comment: your checkbox doesnt have any other attributes, read some docs on html checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This filter is used to manipulate the value of your URL link, not the input type of it.

```
wpdatatables_filter_link_cell( $formattedValue, $tableId )
This filter is applied to the value of an URL link column before it is passed to the front-end.This description provided by your plugin.

$formattedValue is the value of the cell.

$tableId is the table identifier from the MySQL table (wp_wpdatatables).
```

Please see more about this filter from your plugin [URL](https://wpdatatables.com/documentation/information-for-developers/filters/)